# Java How can a List hold both supertype and subtype at the same time?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, arraylist

I have a class, say `Animal` and a subclass `Dog`. I want to have a `List` named `allAnimals` that can hold both `Animal` objects and `Dog` objects at the same time. Currently, it is set up as `List<Animal> allAnimals`. I want to be able to perform two tasks:

1. **Add supertypes and subtypes**.

   ```
   List<Dogs> dogs = new List<>();
   ...
   allAnimals.addAll(dogs);
   ```
2. **I want to be able to pass any subtype or supertype to a list as a parameter in a method.**

   ```
   public void foo(List<Animal> animals){...}
   ...
   foo(allAnimals);
   or
   foo(dogs);
   ```

Is the above possible? wildcard `<? extends Animal>` is giving an error in this case since `foo` is both putting things in the list and taking them out. Do I need to make `Animal` class abstract in order to achieve this?

Comment: `allAnimals.addAll(dogs);` should work fine.

Comment: yes, but point no. 2 will not work. (I edited 2. slightly)

Comment: If `foo` is both putting things in and taking things out, then you should _not_ pass a `List<Dog>`. `foo` can't know what kind of list is passed in, so what type of object is it going to add to the list? Note that only dogs can be added to a `List<Dog>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<? super Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<>();
animalList.add(new Animal());
animalList.add(new Dog("Snoopy"));
animalList.addAll(dogs);
```

so this list is mutable and can hold all Animals and its sub-classes like dog.
Be aware that `List<Dog>` is not an instance of `List<Animal>`.

for your second task method overloading might be nesseccary, depending on what you want to do with the list

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public void accept(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
        List<? super Animal> container = new ArrayList<>();
        container.add(animals.get(0));
        System.out.println(animals);
    }
    public void test() {
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        accept(animals);

        List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        accept(dogs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `List` is it specified: `addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` so it works:

```
animals.addAll(dogs);
```

The same for your method:

```
void foo(List<? extends Animal> animals) {
}
```

A supertype of the specified is not possible (`foo(new Object()`) as parameter.